# Can I use the GNAT Community Edition IDE with Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, ada, gnat

Please can someone tell me how to open the GNAT Community Edition IDE using a Debian 9 OS?

I'm used to using Centos 7, and I would open the IDE like so:
`/home/parallels/opt/GNAT/2020/bin/gps`

However, I can see that there is no gps file in the bin when I install GNAT CE 2020 for Debian.
Does this mean there is no IDE for Debian and you just use the tools from the command line?

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: GNAT CE 2020 runs on Debian. Try ```gnatstudio``` instead of ```gps``` at the end to start the GNAT Studio IDE.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @DeeDee 

Answer (score 1):

GNAT CE 2020 runs on Debian.

The product and its main executable have been renamed around 2019.

Use `gnatstudio` instead of `gps` at the end to start the GNAT Studio IDE.